# How can I allow a user to buy a consumable item and also give them a non-consumable as a reward?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, in-app-purchase

Basically just as the title says, I'm making a mobile game and I'm wondering how I can go about letting the user buy a consumable (coins) and also give them a non-consumable as a bonus (Double Coins Forever)?

Sure I could just activate the double coins upon purchase, but my problems are:

1. How do I stop the user from accidentally buying (and seeing for that matter) the Double Coins purchase button again.
2. How can I restore the purchase if they require it for some reason, without restoring the coins also

Thank you very much, I appreciate any help you can give me!

Comment: After they complete the consumable purchase you can unlock access to a zero cost non-consumable purchase and they can "buy" that.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you I appreciate that! I kinda did think of that earlier, but say they log in from another device, how do I restore a purchase if the zero-cost one is hidden again?

Comment: They would just tap the "restore purchases" button and it will be restored. It's a non-consumable so they don't actually have to ever buy it again

Comment: @Paulw11 Hmmm good point, thank you! - I just tried to create a non-consumable on Google Play and it wouldn't let the price be anything below $0.99, do you know how I can make a free one? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: I don't know about Google.  In iOS you can price a non-consumable at 0.

Comment: Well you could try something like, User purchased Consumable Product (Coins) => Give additional coins to them, just as you'd add the coins to user account, & keep a boolean flag in sharedPreferences, say `doubleRewardGiven`, then when the user presses the Double Coins button, check if the `doubleRewardGiven` is `true`, if `true`, tell the user that they already have them.

Comment: @DarShan thank you I really appreciate it! Your comment has lead me to using CloudOnce to save the fact that they have DoubleCoins so they can login from another phone and it's all good

Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call [queryPurchaseHistoryAsync](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#querypurchasehistoryasync) and grant the privilege (Double Coins) to the user in case the related non-zero-cost in-app item was purchased.